# How to make Notepad++ autocomplete with "end" word in Ruby?

Tags: notepad++, autocomplete, ruby, ruby1.9

Is it possible to set the Notepad++ that it would automaticly put `end` after I print `class` instruction:

```
class MyClass  // right after I print the first whitespace after 'class' instruction...
end  // ...NP++ automatically puts 'end' on the next line OR on the same line (let it be as an option)
```

And the same with `def` instruction word:

```
def method // a whitespace after 'def'...
end  // ...'end' immediatly appears on the next or on the same line
```

Are there any other written-in-C editors that offer `end` autocomplete for Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

While I, for one, have not found anything in Notepad++, perhaps you might want to take a look at Eclipse with the Aptana plugin (I have verified that it adds the "end" for both classes and methods).